# Encountering IndexOutOfBoundsException while implementing ArrayList function in Java to reverse array'

Tags: java

**Given an array/list 'ARR' of integers and a position ‘M’. You have to reverse the array after that position. You do not need to print anything, it has already been taken care of. Just implement the given function.**
This is my problem statement. The following is the code I tried implementing.

```
public class Solution 
{
    public static void reverseArray(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int m)
    {
        
        int i=0,p=1;
        int n=arr.size();
        ArrayList<Integer> reverseArray=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            reverseArray.add(0);
        }
        for(;i<=m;i++){
            reverseArray.set(i, arr.get(i));
        }
        for(;i<n;i++){
            reverseArray.set(i,arr.get(n-p));
        }
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            arr.set(i,reverseArray.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting runtime error as

```
Exception in thread  main  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at Solution.reverseArray(Solution.java:21)
    at Runner.executeAndPrintOutput(Runner.java:50)
    at Runner.main(Runner.java:61)
```

Content of arr={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Comment: And what value have you provided for `m`? This is where a [mcve] is really helpful... (It doesn't help that we don't know what line it's failing on - you haven't included imports, so clearly there's more to the code than this, which means we don't know which line is 21.) Have you stepped through the code in a debugger?

Comment: m=3. Looking at this, at `Solution.reverseArray(Solution.java:21)` the problem lies here, `reverseArray.set(i, arr.get(i));` I don't know how to debug this

Comment: *I don't know how to debug this*  - what do you mean you don't know how to debug this? The error message tells you that you have an index of 6, when the maximum can only be 5. So you add display statements in your code to figure out why the value is 6 and then fix the problem. This is how all basic debugging works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your problem is that in the last loop you are using `i`, instead of `j`. Second, your logic seems faulty to me. Here is a simple solution I've programmed -

```java
public static void reverseArray(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int m) {

    int i = 0, p = 1;
    int n = arr.size();
    ArrayList<Integer> reverseArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (i = m; i < n; i++){
        reverseArray.add(arr.get(n - i - 1 + m));
    }
    for (i = m; i < n; i++){
        arr.set(i, reverseArray.get(i - m));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well thanks a lot, `i` and `j` was that problem as you said. feels so stupid realizing how minor the mistake was.

Comment: @AnandhakrishnanPillai: Rather than just moving on now this is fixed, I'd strongly encourage you to take this as a learning opportunity - in particular, learning how to step through code in a debugger, watching all the variable values etc.

Comment: I agree. Also - when you get an index out of bounds exception, it's always a good practice to check what variables you're using to access your datastructure

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this? remove the print statements before submitting.

```
private void reverseArray(List<Integer> src, int pos) {
    int j = 0;
    Integer[] srcArr = new Integer[src.size()];
    Integer[] tarArr = new Integer[src.size()];
    src.toArray(srcArr);
    src.toArray(tarArr);
    for(int i=pos; i<srcArr.length; i++) {
        j++;
        int tarIndex = srcArr.length-j;
        int tarEle = srcArr[tarIndex]; 
        tarArr[i] = tarEle;
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i<tarArr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(tarArr[i] + " ");
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe the values should be in the original ArrayList once the function terminates

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> reverseList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=arr.size()-1; i>m; i--){
        reverseList.add(arr.get(i));
    }
    int j=0;
    for(int i=m+1; i<arr.size(); i++){
        arr.set(i, reverseList.get(j));
        j++;
    }
```

Comment: As I understood the question (and verified by looking at the original problem on [Coding Ninjas](https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/problem-details/reverse-the-array_1262298) named _Reverse The Array_), the resulting list should be `{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5}`, however your `reverseList` is only `{6, 5}`. Therefore, I would say that your answer is incorrect. Apart from that, [code only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers) are not considered good quality answers. Consider adding explanation of how your code works.

Comment: I think it was asking to reverse from mth position..That's why i solved like this...can u please elaborate your answer in detail.